# I want to flip numbers in an array with a certain probability

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to flip numbers (0/1s) from a certain numpy array with a given probability, say p=0.2.

I have thought of the following solution (using `np.logical_not` and a mask of numbers which is created with p), which however does not yield the expected results:

```
>> arr = np.array([[0,1,1,0,],[1,1,0,1],[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]],dtype=bool)

>> arr

array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])

>> flip_mask = np.array(np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.8, 0.2], size = arr.shape),
                     dtype=bool)
>> flip_mask

array([[False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]])

>> np.logical_not(arr, where=flip_mask)

array([[ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True]])
```

My understanding from the definition of mask, is that the first element (0,0) should remain as is (False), since the mask has the value of False in 0,0.
However this is not the case in the example above.

Comment: When I use your `logical_not` on the given `arr` and `flip_mask`, I get the expected output, not the result you show.  Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How could this be possible?

Comment: I also do not understand in what means my example is not minimal and reproducible. I understand the example and sequence of functions used is somewhat more complicated, as the problem seems to be in the combination of `logical_not` with `where`, but other than that I see no harm in explaining what I am trying to do, in case some other simpler solution exists.

Comment: We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem   We cannot do this with the interactive posting.  The random factor also prevents direct reproduction.

Comment: @MadPhysicist There is also still the problem that, using the values above, the problem does not reproduce.

Comment: @Prune. I was able to reproduce. Took a few tries of allocating non-zero garbage arrays, deleting them, and hoping to end up in the same memory. I've explained what's going on in my answer.

Comment: Good; OPs problem is solved, then.

Comment: @Prune. Agreed. I think that this question is completely valid, and does provide an MCVE, even if it is hard to reproduce sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the docs for the ufunc [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) keyword, it says:

> *New in version 1.7.*
>
> Accepts a boolean array which is broadcast together with the operands. Values of True indicate to calculate the ufunc at that position, values of False indicate to leave the value in the output alone. This argument cannot be used for generalized ufuncs as those take non-scalar input.
> Note that if an uninitialized return array is created, values of False will leave those values **uninitialized**.

Emphasis not mine.

You are seeing the effects of that when the new array is allocated into a chunk of memory that has random garbage. To mitigate, you need to initialize an output buffer with the correct values. There are two possibilities here:

**In Place:**

```
np.logical_not(arr, where=flip_mask, out=arr)
```

This just flips the values directly in `arr` and leaves everything else untouched.

You can do the same thing with boolean indexing, but less efficiently, since you apply the index twice:

```
arr[flip_mask] = ~arr[flip_mask]
```

Another way is to apply [`logical_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_xor.html) (`^`) instead of [`logical_not`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html):

```
arr ^= flip_mask
```

OR

```
np.logical_xor(arr, flip_mask, out=arr)
```

The XOR solutions are likely the most efficient since they don't convert the mask to an index, requiring only one very fast pass over the array.

**New Array:**

```
np.logical_not(arr, where=flip_mask, out=arr.copy())
```

This version copies the original array. It's a good choice if the probability of a flip is low.

```
np.where(flip_mask, ~arr, arr)
```

Using `where` is a bit inefficient since it computes `logical_not` for the entire array.

You can use indexing for this option as well:

```
out = np.empty_like(arr)
out[~flip_mask] = arr[~flip_mask]
out[flip_mask] = ~arr[flip_mask]
```

And of course, XOR:

```
out = arr ^ flip_mask
```

To see why XOR is the same as flipping a mask, look at the following truth table:

```
  arr | flip | out
------+------+------
   T  |   T  |   F
   F  |   T  |   T
   T  |   F  |   T
   F  |   F  |   F
```

Answer (score 1):

@MadPhysicist has a good explanation for why the code doesn't work.

Since you have 0/1 to start with, one way you can flip them is by subtracting a random array of 0/1 with a defined probability, then taking the absolute:

```
np.random.seed(222)
idx = np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.8, 0.2],size=arr.shape)

array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

flipped = abs(arr - idx)
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

And your original array:

```
arr.astype(int)
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I started looking into subtracting booleans after reading this. The most efficient solution is XOR

Comment: Although not very intuitive but yes XOR would work here

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
>>> arr

array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])

>>> flip_mask = np.array(np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.8, 0.2], size = arr.shape),
                     dtype=bool)
>>> flip_mask
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False, False]])
>>> np.where(flip_mask, np.logical_not(arr), arr)
array([[False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

Comment: This is still not the expected result. the 2nd item in the first row was initially True, the flip_mask was also True, but eventually it did not flip to False

Comment: @tony.crete Actually not, my mistake, I should have mentioned. I did it with my own example. I will update.

Comment: Please use my code with your `flip_mask` and check if it works (I am sure it will).

Comment: While this provide an alternative (less than optimal one), it does not address the actual problem. In OP's otherwise more efficient code.